# Connect to Azure Analysis Service with Adomd Client via Microsoft Account

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services, adomd.net

I'm trying to connect to Azure Analysis Service databases (which isn't owned and managed by me) with Adomd client library.

I can connect to them with Power Query connector using Microsoft account, but I couldn't find the correct connection string to prompt me to login with my Microsoft account then use that credential to connect in Adomd. Using the connection string in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-connect

```
"Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=<Azure AS instance name>;"
```

leads to this error

```
Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available?
```

Is it doable with Adomd client?

Comment: The MS learn site you reference in your question shows two ways to create a connection string with a user name and password. Do they not work?

Comment: I don't have a service principal for that. I also did try with my org username + password but it returns "authentication method isn't authorized".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out pythonnet prevents interactive login. I makes it work by using the client library in C#.